# Create multiple UDP servers using golang

Tags: go, udp

I have a list of ports that I need to create a UDP server. I have tried this aproach

```
for _, r := range routingTable.Routes {
        if r.Metric == 0 {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp4", &r.OriginPort)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatalf("Error occured starting the server: %s", err)
                } else {
                    log.Printf("Listening on port: %s", r.OriginPort.String())
                }
                defer conn.Close()

                buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
                for {
                    conn.ReadFromUDP(buffer)
                }
            }()
            wg.Wait()
        }
    }
```

but it is not working. What can I do to make it work ?

Comment: The loop stops on `wg.Wait()`.   Move the call out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. as noted by @CeriseLimon : don't make the goroutine block on each iteration, move `wg.Wait()` outside of the loop
2. don't forget to call `wg.Done()` from within each goroutine : add a call to `defer wg.Done()` in each function

(since your listening goroutines never return, the second point is a bit theoretical ... obviously, add some code to have your listening goroutines do something, and exit cleanly if possible)